# Woocommerce tags in search results

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to include in search results, results matching also product tags. By default it shows results matching product title / description.
Is it possible to add saerching via product tags? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Be default you can not search by product tags. You have to edit you search query backend code to achieve searching via tags as well.

This widget might be close to what you need: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/widgets/product-filter-tags/

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I need to add search in tags in default woocommerce searching (because I'm also using ajax filtering and it shows results based on default woocommerce searching).

But thank you for assistance.